# How can we remove the header of a csv while fetching it from urllib.requests.header

Tags: python-3.x

How can we remove the header of CSV while fetching it with urllib.requests.urlretrieve

CODE:

**urllib.requests.urlretrieve**

**import urllib.request**

**urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/pima-indians-diabetes-database/downloads/diabetes.csv", FILE_DATA)**

Comment: you import is before the call to `urllib.request` ?

Comment: import urllib.request


FILE_DATA = 'veva'

urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/pima-indians-diabetes-database/downloads/diabetes.csv", FILE_DATA)

Comment: this is my code.

Comment: no, i have posted this again. please check once

Comment: can you update your question?